# Help to recognize spider

Tags: zoology, species-identification

It is unusual to see such size spiders in Lithuania, so I was wondering what kind of spider it is and if it is strong enough to bite through humans skin.
I've googled for biggest known spiders in Lithuania, but mentioned few species don't look alike - mine has way thinner legs, but I'm not an expert.
I've placed 1 euro cent coin for size - it's diameter is 16.25mm
[image: spider 1]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The long hairy legs make me think that this might be a spider belonging to the [Tegenaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegenaria) genus, or something related.

Comment: I agree it's a *Tegenaria* spider, probably [*Tegenaria parietina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegenaria_parietina).

Comment: So Tegenaria helped me search further and it looks like it is [Tegenaria atrica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_house_spider) - turns out it is not so rare in Northern Europe, male leg span can be up to 75mm, mine was shorter, but still amazing to watch how fluently those long legs move.

Comment: Yes it looks like Tegenaria. We have plenty of these trying to get in the houses in autumn in Switzerland (not as North as Lituania but cold winter time)